# basic emacs commands not working preventing saving of files

Tags: unix, emacs

I am operating in a linux environment (not familiar to me) and I am handling a bunch of files in django. Bit embarrassing but I seem to have done something subtle to the server that disallows me from setting up separate work stations from my terminal... i.e. `emacs file.py &` won't work for me; it just says that the emacs window is loading but it won't actually appear - I've waited 5 minutes.

It's not a big deal as `emacs file.py` works fine and I can "Reset terminal" once I'm done editing the file. However, saving the file could be a problem as the saving options are different between the "&" and "without &" versions of the command. It's such a basic thing that there seems to be no info on it online... any tips?

NOTE: it all started when I mistakenly typed `emacs file.py` and forgot the `&` and now something seems to be irreversibly changed that logging in and out again doesn't fix...

Comment: The "&" runs the process in the background.  Are you trying to do this remotely without X11?  Also, what do you mean by "saving options are different between the '&' and 'without &' versions of the command"?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Python nor Django.

Answer (score 0):

When using emacs in a text terminal, start it without the `&`, you need to run it in foreground. To save a file, use the standard <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-s</kbd> (if your terminal interprets the keystrokes differently, you have to configure the terminal). After saving the file, you can get back to the shell by pressing <kbd>C-z</kbd>. It would stop emacs, but you can get back in by typing `fg` or `%em` or similar.

To quit emacs, use <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-c</kbd>.